# HERE REST API Error: "Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong."

Tags: php, here-api

I am trying to get an access token in HERE REST API using PHP, but keep getting an error saying "Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong.".

I'm following instructions on this page: https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/access_control/api-reference-swagger.html but they don't provide clear example of generating the signature and I've tried every possible combination/method that I can think of.

Here is my code:

```
function getHereApiAccessToken()
{
    $API_URL="https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";

    $nonce=uniqid();
    $signing_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx_x-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //here.access.key.secret

    $signature_elements=array();
    $signature_elements['oauth_consumer_key']="xxxx_xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx";
    $signature_elements['oauth_nonce']=$nonce;
    $signature_elements['oauth_signature_method']="HMAC-SHA256";
    $signature_elements['oauth_timestamp']=time();
    $signature_elements['oauth_version']="1.0";

    ksort($signature_elements);

    $base_string="";

    foreach($signature_elements as $key=>$val)
    {
        $base_string.=urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($val).'&';
    }

    $base_string=rtrim($base_string, "&");

    $signature=hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $signing_key, true);

    $signature_base64=base64_encode($signature);

    $headers=array();
    $headers[]="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $headers[]='Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'.urlencode($signature_elements['oauth_consumer_key']).'", oauth_nonce="'.urlencode($nonce).'", oauth_signature="'.urlencode($signature_base64).'", oauth_signature_method="'.urlencode($signature_elements['oauth_signature_method']).'", oauth_timestamp="'.time().'", oauth_version="'.urlencode($signature_elements['oauth_version']).'"';

    $postData=array();
    $postData['grant_type']="client_credentials";
    $postData['expires_in']=50;

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
    $response=curl_exec($ch);

    br($response);

    $httpcode=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        echo "cURL error: ". curl_error($ch);

        return false;
    }
        elseif($httpcode!=200)
        {
            echo "API responded with HTTP code: ". $httpcode;

            echo "<br><br />Response: ".$response;

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            curl_close($ch);

            $json=json_decode($response, 1);

            br($json);

            if(empty($json))
            {
                echo "Failed to decode JSON";

                return false;
            }

            if(empty($json['access_token']))
            {
                echo "Missing access_token in API response: ".var_export($json, true);
            }

            return $json['access_token'];
        }

    return false;
}
```

And a copy of the error response:

```
{"errorId":"ERROR-c3d5c184-f2c9-4edb-a85c-2dd4c6d7e0d1","httpStatus":401,"errorCode":401300,"message":"Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong.","error":"invalid_client","error_description":"errorCode: '401300'. Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong."}
```

Comment: your URL suggests that you are in a oauth2 context, yet your code seems to be oauth1'ish .

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I've noticed that, but that's how it's specced up in HERE's documentation. https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/access_control/api-reference-swagger.html

Comment: _“but they don't provide clear example”_ - https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/access_control/topics/creating-signature.html -> https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process complete explanation of the whole process in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue, here is working code:

```
function generate_string($input, $strength = 16) {
    $input_length = strlen($input);
    $random_string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
        $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
        $random_string .= $random_character;
    }
 
    return $random_string;
}


$httpUrl = "https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";
    
    $permitted_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    $nonce= generate_string($permitted_chars, 6);
    
    $signature_elements=array();
    
    $signature_elements['grant_type']="client_credentials";
    $signature_elements['oauth_consumer_key']="#here.access.key.id#";//from config file
    $signature_elements['oauth_nonce']=$nonce;
    $signature_elements['oauth_signature_method']="HMAC-SHA256";
    $signature_elements['oauth_timestamp']=time();
    $signature_elements['oauth_version']="1.0";

    $signing_key="#here.access.key.secret#"; //from config file

    $base = 'POST'
            . '&' . rawurlencode($httpUrl)
            . '&' . rawurlencode('grant_type=client_credentials&oauth_consumer_key=' . $signature_elements['oauth_consumer_key'])
            . rawurlencode('&oauth_nonce=' . $signature_elements['oauth_nonce'])
            . rawurlencode('&oauth_signature_method=' . $signature_elements['oauth_signature_method'])
            . rawurlencode('&oauth_timestamp=' . $signature_elements['oauth_timestamp'])
            . rawurlencode('&oauth_version=' . $signature_elements['oauth_version']);

    $key = rawurlencode($signing_key) . '&';

    $signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $base, $key, true)));

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $httpUrl,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" . $signature_elements['oauth_consumer_key'] . "\",oauth_signature_method=\"" . $signature_elements['oauth_signature_method'] . "\",oauth_timestamp=\"" . $signature_elements['oauth_timestamp'] . "\",oauth_nonce=\"" . $signature_elements['oauth_nonce'] . "\",oauth_version=\"" . $signature_elements['oauth_version'] . "\",oauth_signature=\"{$signature}\"",
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_decode($response, true));
    echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was to read the documentation carefully
https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/sdk.html#step-2-create-a-signature

Especially this sentence needs attention:
The signing key is the URL-encoded access key secret, **followed by an ampersand ("&").**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).